# Client side scripting. e.g. validating a form and need it to only accept a "/" or numbers for expiry date.

Tags: javascript, html

Anyway I've tried pretty hard but I'm still struggling.

Essentially what I need to do is validate a form for an assignment.

I need to make sure the email format is valid, which I assume only includes ".", "@", numbers and letters.

I need to make sure one part of the form only accepts alpha numeric characters

I need to make sure at least one box has been ticked

and as I said in the title, make sure the expiry date box only accepts a "/" or numbers.

Any help or tips would be hugely appreciated because I'm absolutely stuffed right now. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Reference here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation . Please come back with a more precise question.

Answer (score 0):

**Validating email**

```
<input pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" required />
```

**I need to make sure one part of the form only accepts alpha numeric characters**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Validate</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <style>
         .widefat-main{
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         function validate() {
            var errorDiv = document.getElementById("errorDiv"),
                    regex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/,
                    str = document.getElementById("inputString").value;

            if ((str.length > 4) && (str.length < 10) && regex.test(str)) {
               errorDiv.innerHTML = "Fine string";
               return true;
            }
            else {
               errorDiv.innerHTML = "4 to 10 alphanumerical characters only";
               return false;
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="" onsubmit="return validate();">
         <input 
            id="inputString"
            type="text" 
            name="url_code" 
            class="widefat-main" 
            title="4 to 10 alphanumerical characters only" 
            />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
      <div id="errorDiv"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**I need to make sure at least one box has been ticked**

```
var f = document.form1;
if (f.summer.checked || f.autumn.checked || f.winter.checked) {
    // we're OK!
}
```

**and as I said in the title, make sure the expiry date box only accepts a "/" or numbers.**

```
var errormessage = "";
 function checkIsValidDateTime(){
      errormessage = "";
      var isvalid = false;
      var dt = document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value;
      var parts = dt.split(" ");
      if(parts.length == 3){
         var date = parts[0];
         var time = parts[1];
         var ampm = parts[2];
         if(ampm.length == 2 && (ampm.toLowerCase() == "am" || ampm.toLowerCase() == "pm")){
            var validformatdate=/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
            if (validformatdate.test(date)){
                var validformattime = /^\d{1,2}:\d{2}$/;
                if (validformattime.test(date)){
                     isvalid = true;
                }else{errormessage = "Time is not in the format HH:MM";}
            }else{errormessage = "Date is not in the format dd/mm/yyyy";}
         }else{errormessage = "DateTime does not have AM/PM at the end";}
      }else{errormessage = "DateTime is not in the format 11/07/2011 3:45 AM";}
      return isvalid;
 }
```

Comment: just to clarify, is this language what client side scripting is?

or is it this for eg. ?

if (document.order.fname.value=="") {
alert("invalid")
document.order.fname.focus();
return false

sorry! I really dont know much

Comment: @gillon yes these are client side scripting (javascript). [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) to know more...

Comment: one other query vishva, for example, this is what the email part of the html says 

<div class="form_row">
                    <label class="contact"><strong>Email:</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="email"/>
                    </div>


what would you add in to your email bit to fit it with this?
thanks again and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: and same with alpha numeric except with this code :    <div class="form_row">
                    <label class="contact"><strong>Company:</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="company"/>
                    </div>